# How to write a function to express "not divisible by 3"?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

This problem is from *Discrete Mathematics and its applications.*

> Determine whether each of these sets is countable or uncountable. For those that are countably infinite, exhibit a one-to-one correspondence between the set of positive integers and that set.
> $\quad 4a)\;\;$  integers not divisible by 3

The example problem that the author gave is the following.

> *Solution*: To show that the set of odd positive integers is countable, we will exhibit a one-to-one correspondence between this set and the set of positive integers. Consider the function $f(n)=2n-1$ from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to the set of odd positive integers.
> We show that $f$ is a one-one correspondence by showing that it is both one-one and onto. To see that it is one-one, suppose $f(n)=f(m).$ Then $2n-1=2m-1$, and so $n=m$.
> To see that $f$ is onto, suppose $t$ is an odd positive integer. Then $t$ is $1$ less than an even integer $2k$, where $k$ is a natural number. Hence $t=2k-1=f(k)$.

For $4a)$, I immediately recognized this set is countable and infinite because you could start listing them out $\{1,2, 5, 7, \dots\}$, and it keeps going on and on, because the set of integers is infinite.

From the example, the author used a function to map the positive counts $(1,2,3,\dots)$ to the set he was testing against (positive odds) with a simple function $f(n) = 2n - 1.$ Having this simple function made it easy for the author to prove one to one (injective). That is if $f(n) = f(m)$, $2n-1 = 2m - 1,$ and so with algebra, $n = m.$

*Is there a similar function I could write for my problem as well, to make proving the one-to-one property easier?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to show to injections. Let $A$ denote the set of integers not divisible by $3$: $A= \{n \in \mathbb Z: 3 \nmid n\}$. Then $f \colon \mathbb Z \to A$ defined by $f(n) = 3n+1$ is injective, which implies $|\mathbb Z| \le |A|$. On the other hand the function $g \colon A \to \mathbb Z$ defined by $g(n) = n$ is injective too, so $|\mathbb Z| \ge |A|$. Combining these two results and Cantor-Bernstein theorem we get $|A| = |\mathbb Z|$.

[EDIT]: One can actually write the bijection explicitly, $h \colon \mathbb N \to A^+$, where $r_2$ denotes the remainder from division by two. Even simplier function would be $i(n) = 2n-1 - \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.

$$h(n) = n+1 - r_2(n) + (n + r_2(n))/2$$

Comment: 3 | n means, 3 divides n or there exists some x such that 3x = n? In this case this x wouldn't exist.

Comment: It means both of them. What you have written is exactly definition of divisibility: $a \mid b$ iff there exists some $k$ for which $b = ak$.

Comment: for Then f:Z→A defined by f(n)=3n+1 is injective, how did you come to that conclusion? I know this a function that maps an integer in the set of integers to an integer in the set of integers not divisible by 3. Where did you get 3n + 1 though from? I know if go though the f(n) = f(m) proof, this should work, 3n + 1 = 3m + 1

Comment: The number $3n+1$ is not divisible by three for sure and the proof you have demonstrated is indeed valid.

Comment: But for the equation 3n + 1, how would you map to 17, which is an element in the set of integers not divisible by 3 from an integer n in Z+? Wouldn't this not be onto then? No way to reach to 17?

Comment: It's not onto, but it does't have to be: do you know what the Cantor-Bernstein theorem says? If not, then just take $h$, which is the bijection you are looking for.

Comment: for Then f:Z→A defined by f(n)=3n+1 is injective, which implies |Z|≤|A|, what rule did you use to imply that the cardinality(size) of A is >= cardinality of Z? Just from intuition, I know that the size of the set of integer is greater than the size of the set of integers that are not divisible by 3 because that set would be a subset of the first.

Comment: yeah my book calls it Schroeder - Bernstein theorem. It doesn't have to be onto

Answer (score 0):

You could define a piecewise function:

$$f(n) = \begin{cases} 3n-1 & n \equiv 1 \pmod3 \\
      3n-2 & n \equiv 2 \pmod3\end{cases}$$
The function is a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $(3\mathbb{Z}-1)\cup(3\mathbb{Z}-2)$, which is basically what you're looking for.

Comment: what does the three equals sign mean?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(n) = \frac{6n-3-(-1)^n}4.$$

Does your discrete mathematics course cover recurrence equations? You can derive this formula by solving the recurrence $f(n)=f(n-2)+3$ with initial values $f(1)=1,f(2)=2$.

Comment: Not yet but we will. I take a look at this when we do :)